# Twitter oAuth request token C#

Tags: c#, twitter

I have Consumer keys. I have can't find out who i should request the token. Can anyone give a exampel off how i should to that? And what about the PIN that i get when i trying? Should all users get a pin and the write that in a textbox eacth time they should login/post a update?

I have look at Linq2Twitter, but don't figure out how to request the token.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to make the API calls yourself, or are you using an already created library(like Linq2Twitter)?

EDITED:  here is a link to using OAuth in Linq2Twitter...

http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2009/08/19/oauth-in-action-linq2twitter.aspx